# Unable to connect Ubuntu 16.04 Server in VirtualBox (host Windows 10) to internet via bridged wireless adapter

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04, internet-connection, bridge

Strange, on work I can normally connect to internet with my Ubuntu 16.04 Server via briged wireless adapter, but at home I can't (when "A start job is running" sequence is over and after I log in to server there is no internet connection). I also tried to connect at friend's place but also result is negative.

Bridging with Lan adapter works perfectly, but I would rather use Wi-fi bridged adapter if I can. NAT or Host-only are not an option.

Is it possible that router that my ISP gave me is problem? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Change the adaptor to wireless, present below Bridged Adapter. And try.